# repo python error on python2.7

Tags: android, python

I create another folder trying to download android source code and get the following error, but for my first Android source code directory, there's no such error.

```
~/AndroidFramework2/bin/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shanwu/AndroidFramework/bin/repo", line 775, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/shanwu/AndroidFramework/bin/repo", line 742, in main
    _Init(args)
  File "/home/shanwu/AndroidFramework/bin/repo", line 266, in _Init
    _Clone(url, dst, opt.quiet)
  File "/home/shanwu/AndroidFramework/bin/repo", line 526, in _Clone
    if _DownloadBundle(url, local, quiet):
  File "/home/shanwu/AndroidFramework/bin/repo", line 466, in _DownloadBundle
    r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1175, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 759, in _tunnel
    line = response.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
TypeError: readline() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: At a guess, you're using an older/newer library.

Comment: thank you for your comment, please give me more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off proxy setting for http/https on my laptop, download repo from google, and this error message doesn't show up anymore.

Comment: which answer ? I am waiting for more detailed answer which should include cause and solution of this kind of problem...

Comment: Oh OK never mind, I presumed that this was a complete fix for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it as sudo. That worked for me.